# Подгрузка комментариев на странице с помощью NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Я новичок в JS. Хочу спарсить комментарии с инстаграма, но для этого их сначала надо все подгрузить. Я использую puppeteer в NodeJs и написал такой код:

`await page.evaluate(() => {
    while(document.querySelector('main').querySelector('ul').querySelector('button'))
      document.querySelector('main').querySelector('ul').querySelector('button').click()
  })`

И... он ничего не делает, запускается бесконечный цикл и виснет браузер. Я пробовал использовать `timeout()`, однако не сработало, если без цикла всё запустить в консоли, то оно сработает, можно даже вручную тыкать пока не появится ошибка, что элемента не существует. В общем-то я того же от цикла и ожидаю: Пока кнопка существует - то нажимать на неё, чтобы в итоге подгрузились все комментарии. Не могу понять почему не срабатывает вообще ничего. Помогите советом или подправьте код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так мне ответили на англоязычном stackoverflow, код рабочий, надеюсь кому нибудь поможет. Используем тут `setInterval`, чтобы замедлить итерации

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const button = document.querySelector('main ul button');
      if (button !== null) {
        button.click();
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 100);
  });
});
```